# Unexpected nil window with XCode 6 Universal application

Tags: iphone, xcode6, ios-universal-app

I converted a working app to be Universal. However after overcoming most problems I am stuck with the following error when I run the app:

```
2015-01-16 13:51:20.663 CREW-Universal[820:13935] unexpected nil window in _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent, _windowServerHitTestWindow: <UIClassicWindow: 0x7fc488c4be80; frame = (0 0; 375 667); userInteractionEnabled = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc488d3ae60>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7fc488c4c750>>
```

This error occurs when I click on the black window (in the simulator) which displays after the launch image appears.

An anyone suggest how I can find out the cause of this problem? (There is no script attached to the initial window.)

Comment: share your code.. r u using story board

Answer (score 1):

```
self.window = [UIWindow new];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
self.window.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

try this

Comment: Eventually I resolved this problem ... it's been some time but I believe I had to remove the storyboard and then re-add it.